# Read/Write Tiffs in Java

Tags: java, open-source, image, awt, tiff

Any ideas for  open-source libraries, with Apache or similar license, for reading and writing TIFF files in Java 5 (Preferably with the AWT image-processing libraries, including  *ImageIO*.)

I'm  aware that Java 6  is supposed to support TIFF. I know about Sun's JAI implementation, but that  [license](https://jai.dev.java.net/jdl-jai.pdf) doesn't work for the company I work at; and Asprise, but that is a commercial product. Sanselan looks good, but that is not yet a released product.

Any recommendations for a another TIFF-reader implementation?

Answer (score 1):

[Freeimage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) should be fairly easy to use from Java - I've used it from C# and VB6.

The only problem with open source image libraries is that they cannot read the JPEG encoded Tiffs (from the TIFF 6.0 standard) that a lot of the commercial scanners create especially with a dirty image.

Libtiff can be recompiled to support it, but I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [**iText**](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/objects/images/index.php) to read/write tiffs.